# Laravel: Search by similar string

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to make a search feature on laravel. now I'm using this query:

```
$products = Product::with(['category', 'store'])
            ->when($keywords, function ($query) use ($keywords) {
                $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $keywords . "%")
                    ->orWhere('description', 'LIKE', '%' . $keywords . '%');
            })->get()
```

The problem is, say on the database i've a product with the name `corrupti`, If i searched by the exact name or removed a character from beginning or end it works fine, but if I changed a single character it returns an empty list.

Users are likely to make typos, so I want to be able to find the product is the user typed `corrupta`, `corrupi` instead of `corrupti`.

I know this is not a simple task to achive, I googled many things but I didn't find a solution.

One thing I've came accross is the php `similar_text` funciton, it may be useful but I didn't find a way to include it in the database query.

Comment: You are already making a `LIKE` match on the database. I'm not really sure how are you managing the indices or what is the expected number of records, what you are trying does not seem to be a candidate for mysql-db querying.

Comment: Also, I would just like to point out, if this is a college project or something or you really not care about efficiency for whatever reason, look into `Levenshtein distance` and `Edit distance match`. You can create a `list` of similar strings and run a `LIKE` match on all of them. I don't recommend this tho

Comment: If you are looking for a full-text search solution, try Laravel [scout](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scout). Multiple drivers are available including inbuilt support for  [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/), [MeiliSearch](https://www.meilisearch.com/) and a collection driver.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.soundex.php
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.metaphone.php

1. use metaphone (or soundex) to encode words you want to be searchable
2. put them in a database column say products.name_as_metaphone
3. make your search function encode searched word to metaphone, then make it look in the metaphone column (and not in product.name)...
4. profit

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$query = Product::query();
    $searches = explode(' ', $request->query('q'));
    
                if (isset($searches)) {
                    foreach ($searches as $search) {
                        $query->where(function ($q) use ($search) {
                            $q->where('code', 'ilike', '%' . $search . '%')
                                ->orWhere('name', 'ilike', '%' . $search . '%');
                        });
                    }
                }
    
                $data = $query->get();
    
                return ([
                    'success'   => true,
                    'response'  => $data,
                    'message'   => 'Your message here'
                ]);
```